# Removing Decimal from whole sheets using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I currently have a report that automatically adds decimal places on to the results but I was wondering whether there is a VBA code that i could use to remove all decimals from the sheet So i don't have to do it manually.

example. 474.40 would need to be reduced to 474. The values would change every time the report is run.

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: There are built-in ways to display your values in almost any format. In your case you would display the values without the fractional part. This can be done by simply assigning a "number format" to the cells in question.

Comment: Isn't it just CTRL + A and then decreasing the number of decimals? You can record that and then use it.

Comment: Thank you @cars10m that really helped me, I recorded it as a Macros, I don't know why I just didn't think of doing it that way in the beginning.

Comment: Range("A1:AX434").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0"
    Sheets("Store Report").Select
    Range("A1:AX434").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0"
    Sheets("RD_SD Report").Select
    Range("A1:AC479").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0"
    Sheets("Top 10").Select
    Range("A1:N21").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0"
    Sheets("Raw Data").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    
    MsgBox "Pivots Updated & Decimals Removed"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply assign the "Number" format to the cells in question and set "Decimal places" to 0:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try some thing like this, select column that you need and round all cell by formula:

```
    Sub RemoveDecimal()
        Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
        Set rng = Range("D1:D20")
        For Each cell In rng
            Debug.Print Round(cell.Value, 0)
        Next cell
    End Sub
```